# Ansible conditional statements not evaluating correctly

Tags: ansible, conditional-statements, ansible-2.x

I have an ansible playbook with a couple of tasks that check a directory for files created on todays date and saves them in `files`. I'm doing my comparison off of  `files|length` and print out two different messages depending if the length is 0 or not.

Here is the code:

```
  - name: Grabbing all of the files that were created today
    shell: find /home/user/empty_directory  -maxdepth 1  -daystart -ctime 0  -print
    register: files

  - debug: var=files.stdout

  - debug: msg="The directory isn't empty"
    when: files|length != 0

  - debug: msg="The directory is empty"
    when: files|length == 0
```

Heres the output:

```
  TASK [debug]
 ok: [server] => {
 "changed": false, 
 "files.stdout": ""
 }

 TASK [debug] 
 ok: [server] => {
"changed": false, 
"msg": "The directory isn't empty"
 }

TASK [debug] 
skipping: [server] => {"changed": false, "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False", "skipped": true}
```

Is there a mistake that I am making which is causing the conditionals to evaluate incorrectly? Because based off of the output `files` is in fact empty

I've tried it without the `|length` and done my comparison off of `files == ""` & `files != ""` and got the same result.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are checking `files|length` instead of `files.stdout|length`. Note that `files` contain a few other variables as well, so it's definitely not empty

Comment: @SztupY - thanks for the help! your suggestion worked. If you post it as an answer I'll shoot it an  up vote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are checking `files|length` instead of `files.stdout|length`. Note that `files` is a dictionary containing a few other elements as well, so it's definitely not empty