# Warning: Ansible evaluating bare variable. How do I implement this correctly?

Tags: ansible, conditional-statements

My Ansible conditional statements are not evaluating correctly.

```
- name: A
  shell:
    cmd: /usr/local/bin/is_A_OK #returns bash true or false (not strings)
  register: is_A_OK

- name: B
  shell:
    cmd: /usr/local/bin/is_B_OK 
  register: is_B_OK

- name: reboot if both are OK
  reboot:
  when:
    - is_A_OK
    - is_B_OK
```

> [DEPRECATION WARNING]: evaluating 'is_A_ok' as a bare variable, this behaviour will go away and you might need to add |bool to the expression in the future. Also see CONDITIONAL_BARE_VARS configuration toggle. This feature will be removed in version 2.12.

However, the logic works correctly, and the reboot is performed when both variables are true. But I can't leave it as-is given that this feature will be removed in version 2.12.

FYI, the bash scripts conclude like this:

```
if [[ "$my_var" == true ]]; then
    true
else
    false
fi
```

I'm running Arch Linux, so bash is new.

The warning plus the ansible [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html) made me think this would be correct:

```
- name: reboot if OK
  reboot:
  when:
    - is_A_OK|bool
    - is_B_OK|bool
```

The warning goes away, but the reboot is not preformed, even when both variables are true. I guess I don't understand the docs. (I'm new to Ansible.)

I found this question, but it is not relevant:
Ansible conditional statements not evaluating correctly - Stack Overflow
[Ansible conditional statements not evaluating correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42700186/ansible-conditional-statements-not-evaluating-correctly)

What am I doing wrong and not understanding?

Comment: When the script opts for `false` the task should crash with `"msg": "non-zero return code"`. Do you ignore errors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer**: Either test the attribute `rc` of the registered dictionary or use [task results](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#task-results) to test success.

**Details**: The return code of the command is stored in the attribute `rc` of the registered dictionary. The command

```yaml
    - command: /bin/true
      register: result_A
    - debug:
        var: result_A.rc
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ (result_A is success)|ternary('OK', 'KO') }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ result_A|ternary('OK', 'KO') }}"
```

returns `rc=0` as a result of `/bin/true`. Use [task results](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#task-results) to test success. Testing of bare variable `result_A` gives `True` because the variable is not empty. It also produces the deprecation warning.

```yaml
    "result_A.rc": "0"
    "msg": "OK"
    "msg": "OK"
```

In the case of `/bin/false` the command

```yaml
    - command: /bin/false
      register: result_B
      ignore_errors: true
    - debug:
        var: result_B.rc
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ (result_B is success)|ternary('OK', 'KO') }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ result_B|ternary('OK', 'KO') }}"
```

returns `rc=1` and the task would fail without `ignore_errors: true`.

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["/bin/false"], "delta": "0:00:00.003322", "end": "2020-06-14 07:07:17.620345", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2020-06-14 07:07:17.617023", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
>   ...ignoring

The test success fails and testing of `result_B` gives `True` because the variable is not empty.

```yaml
    "result_B.rc": "1"
    "msg": "KO"
    "msg": "OK"
```